# Why does my for loop not work inside my class before render method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I founds several answers here actually addressing this problem, which is why I found my general approach. But as most answers say, insert the code snippet:

```
var squares =[];

for(let i=1; i<10; i++){

    squares.push(<div className="square" key={i}></div>);       
}
```

inside the class before the render method. But it does not work. Then I put the same code outside off the class and it works but now I have no access to the state scope (if I am not mistaken). I am also confused, why my code editor wouldn't let me change var to let (inside class).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say it "does not work", what do you mean? Does it throw an error? Does it produce a result you weren't expecting?

Comment: Can you show the full code?  What do you mean by "before the render method"?

Comment: Also, what code editor are you using?

Comment: If that code isn't inside a class method it will fail because you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> most answers say insert the code snippet inside the class before the render method. But it does not work.

Those answers probably meant this:

```
someMethod() {
  var squares =[];

  for(let i=1; i<10; i++){
     squares.push(<div className="square" key={i}></div>);       
  }
}

render() {
  return (
     // ...
  )
}
```

Whereas you're probably doing this:

```
var squares =[];

for(let i=1; i<10; i++){
   squares.push(<div className="square" key={i}></div>);       
}

render() {
  return (
     // ...
  )
}
```

> Then I put the same code outside off the class and it works but now I
>   have no access to the state scope

Correct, that is how it should be.

I also suspect that you want to display this on the screen, in which case you should also return it:

```
someMethod() {
  var squares =[];

  for(let i=1; i<10; i++){
     squares.push(<div className="square" key={i}></div>);       
  }
  return squares;
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
     {this.someMethod()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But as most answers say, insert the code snippet inside the class
>   before the render method.

No you would not insert the for loop directly within the class outside the render method, but directly inside it

```
render () {
    var squares =[];
    for(let i=1; i<10; i++){
       squares.push(<div className="square" key={i}></div>);       
    }
    return (
       <div>{squares}</div>
    )
}
```